# Spark error on cogroup using same dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sbt

Below is the snippet of spark code with simple transformations:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

final case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("CreateDataFrameExample")
      .master("local[*]") // Set the master to local mode for local testing
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    // Create some sample data
    val data = Seq(
      Row("Alice", 25),
      Row("Bob", 30),
      Row("Charlie", 22),
      Row("Charlie", 22)

    )
    // Define the schema for the DataFrame
    val schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("Name", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("Age", IntegerType, nullable = true)
    ))

    // Create a DataFrame
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
    
    val ds_name = df.as[Person].groupByKey(_.name)
    val ds_age = df.as[Person].groupByKey(_.name)

    val ds_cg = ds_name.cogroup(ds_age)((_, it1, _) => it1).groupByKey(_.name)

    val z = ds_cg.mapGroups { case (k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x.name).toArray) }
    z.show(10)
```

I am using the same Dataframe for a groupByKey and then grouping them. This gives me the following error:

```
Driver stacktrace:
[error] org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 24) (MUUWLP2212.int.msci.com executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find name#2 in [Name#31,Age#32]
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:80)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:73)
```

But when I change it to the following:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
val df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
  

val ds_name = df.as[Person].groupByKey(_.name)
val ds_age = df_1.as[Person].groupByKey(_.name)

val ds_cg = ds_name.cogroup(ds_age)((_, it1, _) => it1).groupByKey(_.name)

println(ds_cg.queryExecution.toString())
val z = ds_cg.mapGroups { case (k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x.name).toArray) }
z.show(10)
```

The above runs successfully when it is essentially the same thing. In the first I am just using the same dataframe in both the groubByKey. This is just an example I created to reproduce an error that is occuring in a similar transformation where same dataframe in used. In that I need to use the same dataframe and can't have two copies.

My build.sbt is following:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "sparkTest"
  )
val sparkVer = "3.3.2"
libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer  ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVer )}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Judging from the error message `IllegalStateException: Couldn't find name#2 in [Name#31,Age#32]`, it's likely just mismatch in column names -- you have `Name` & `Age` in the Dataframe schema and `name` & `age` in case class `Person`.

Comment: In that case why does the second one work. Changing the names in case class gives me the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find name#2 in [name#25,age#26]